# Resume upload after internet connection is interrupted using S3 JS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to upload large files (usually greater than 5GB) using AWS S3 JS SDK via its multipart upload API. Files are getting successfully uploaded but I have one issue when the internet connection is lost, when the upload is in progress and when the connection resumes then the upload process halt and I have to re-upload the file from the beginning.
Is there a way to automatically resume the upload process when the lost internet connection resumes?
Below is the sample js code I am using for upload:

```
s3.upload({
    Key: filePath,
    Body: file,
    ACL: 'public-read'
}, options, function(err, data) {

    if(err) {`enter code here`
        // handle your error here
    }else{
        // handle successful upload action here
    }
}).on('httpUploadProgress', function (progress) {
    // Show upload progress bar / loader here
    var uploaded = parseInt((progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total);
});
```

[image: Console error]

Comment: Maybe this is what can help to progress in the task. I'm curious if it helps. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html

Comment: is there any solution for this, any example?